# SqlAlchemy Interface Error

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm setting up a facebook style messaging system with the following model setup:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=False)
    all_conversations = db.relationship('Conversation',
        primaryjoin='or_(User.id == Conversation.user1_id, User.id == ' \
        'Conversation.user2_id)', lazy='dynamic')
    # Replies where this is this user.
    replies = db.relationship("Reply", backref="user", lazy='dynamic')

class Conversation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    user2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))        
    user1 = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user1_id], 
        backref='conversations_as_user1')       
    user2 = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user2_id], 
        backref='conversations_as_user2')
    # Replies to this conversation.
    replies = db.relationship("Reply", backref="conversation", lazy='dynamic')


class Reply(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    reply = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    conversation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("conversation.id"))
```

However, each time I try to add a reply object to the database and then commit it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 721, in commit
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 354, in commit
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 334, in _prepare_impl
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1818, in flush
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1936, in _flush
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 58, in __exit__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1900, in _flush
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 372, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 525, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 64, in save_obj
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 569, in _emit_insert_statements
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 662, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 761, in _execute_clauseelement
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 195, in raise_from_cause
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
```

From doing some tests, I've discovered, that reply gets posted in the database when I get rid of any foreign keys, but either and/or both keys cause it to throw this error. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: I seemed to be able to get the model to work with sqlite and plain sqlalchemy.  Can you add the code you are using to actually write the data to the database?  What database are you using?

Comment: Wow that's really strange, I'm using sqlite as well. I create a reply object and it worse fine. To push it to the database I'm using the following code (where x is the reply object): `db.session.add(x)` and then `db.session.commit()`

Comment: I'm not using flask sqlalchemy though, how do you create the reply object?

Comment: I'm creating the Reply object by simply adding the parameters when creating Reply, i.e. `Reply(<text>, <user>, <convo>)`. I have an init function so I believe this should work